проблема с импортом моделей в django
не видит весь проект django, а именно в импорте from myapp2.models import Client

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp2.models import Client
    
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Create user."
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        client = Client(name='John', email='john@example.com',
        phone_number="893242", address='secret12', registration_date='25.05.2002')
        client.save()
        self.stdout.write(f'{client}') 

Есть код команды в django. Хочу, чтобы через команду создавался клиент. Но программа не видит myapp
в  settings.py прописал
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'myapp2',
...
]

миграцию тоже делал, все эти команды прописывал:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

в конце не было никакой ошибки. Также скачивал другой проект через github в zip: выходит такая же ошибка. Когда клонировал через git, то все норм


Неплохо бы увидеть код ошибки

Попробовал запустить команду python manage.py create_Client  отработала без ошибки. Хотя pycharm подсвечивает как ошибка
